# Not able to import images using feed image grabber module in content image field

Tags: media, feeds

I am using Feed and Feed Image grabber module for importing data form non Drupal site to my Drupal Site. All fields are successfully imported except image field, I have checked all the steps to FIG module configuration but with no success.

I have also tried for new content type but again no success.
My CSV file have following data
Title,Description,image
Test1, testdescription,https://s3.amazonaws.com/brewerydbapi/brewery/snQlvg/upload_qMSc0A-medium.png

When file imports, only first two columns data saved not image and also no error shows in logs also.

Please confirm whether we can use external links or not?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Finally with a struggle for more than a day, I finally get succeeded in importing images in Drupal Content type.

I used [Feed Image Grabber](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/feeds_imagegrabber-7.x-1.0-alpha2.zip) Module with feed but not works for me might be my image path is from external server.

Then I used [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media), [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) and [Media Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_feeds) module which gives me ability to import images from external URL too.

1. After all the above modules get enabled.
2. I have added one more mapping "source->target" in my Feeds Importer under Mappings and Select "Target Field" appended with "(media_internet)(field_image)" and then save.
3. Then upload CSV file and finally my images start getting saved in
   image field.

Hope this will help someone.